# Issues with regex to match JSON-like string with optionally missing [] brackets around lists

Tags: python, regex, pandas

The following string is a typical example of the format of JSON input strings that I need to convert to a pandas DataFrame. My attempted work flow is to:

1. split String into List (see String below, note this represents an individual row)
2. Convert each list to a dictionary
3. Convert dictionary to a pd.DataFrame
4. Merge DataFrames together

**Input String:** (Representing one row of Data)

```
"PN_#":9999,"Item":"Pear, Large","Vendor":["Farm"],"Class":["Food","Fruit"],"Sales Group":"59","Vendor ID (from Vendor)":[78]
```

**Desired Output List:**

````
{'PN_#':9999,
'Item':"Pear, Large",
'Vendor':"Farm",
'Class':"Food,Fruit",
'Sales Group':59,
'```
Vendor ID (from Vendor)':78}
````

**Attempt:**
I have been using `re.split` to attempt this. For most cases this is not an issue, however the items such as *"Class":["Food","Fruit"]* and `"Item":"Pear, Large"` are proving to be challenging to account for.

This regex solves the issues of the latter case, however it obviously does not work for the former:

```
re.split("(?=[\S]),(?=[\S])",data)
```

I have tried a multitude of expressions to completely satisfy my requirements. The following expression is generally representative of what I have attempted unsuccessfully:

```
regex.split("(?!\[.+?\s),(?=[\S])(?!.+?\])", data)
```

Any suggestion or solutions for how to accomplish this, or suggestion if I am going about this the wrong way?

Comment: That's not quite valid JSON, the [] are needed around a list: `"Item":"Pear, Large"` unlike `"Class":["Food","Fruit"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is a valid JSON without braces. Add the braces and use `json.loads` to get the JSON object.

Next, just iterate the object, and if the current key contains a list of strings, join them:

```py
import json
s='"PN_#":9999,"Item":"Pear, Large","Vendor":["Farm"],"Class":["Food","Fruit"],"Sales Group":"59","Vendor ID (from Vendor)":[78]'
js = json.loads(f'{{{s}}}')
for key in js:
    if isinstance(js[key], list): # is it a list?
        if all(isinstance(x, str) for x in js[key]): # is it a list of strings?
            js[key] = ",".join(js[key])
        else:
            js[key] = ",".join(map(str, js[key]))
print(js)
```

Output:

```
{'PN_#': 9999, 'Item': 'Pear, Large', 'Vendor': 'Farm', 'Class': 'Food,Fruit', 'Sales Group': '59', 'Vendor ID (from Vendor)': '78'}
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/hjPjA2).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This nearly works, the only issue is that there are two values for the key 'Class' not one.

Comment: @MountainFish You can join the string values. See the updated answer.

Comment: I think I almost have it. The following joins everything as needed except a list of of numbers:      `for key,value in temp_row.items():
        try:
            if isinstance(temp_row[key], list):
                temp_row[key] = ','.join(value)
        except:
            pass` sorry I'm new to posting and experiencing issues including code in a comment

Comment: @MountainFish See the updated answer. It will now cast to `str` all the lists where the items are not all strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciated it and I have now upvoted your answer.

Comment: That's not valid JSON, the [] are needed around a list: `"Item":"Pear, Large"` unlike `"Class":["Food","Fruit"]`